# In boost build, how to set compiler options conditionally?

Tags: boost-build

Is there a way (without modifying source files) to specify that I want to build boost with, say, msvc with one set of additional options in debug and another in release variants? In some config.jam or even better on command line? Like

```
using msvc : : <compileflags>-DRELEASE_DEFINES; - only if variant=release
using msvc : : <compileflags>-DDEBUG_DEFINES; - only if variant=debug
using msvc : : <compileflags>-DLL_SPECIFIC_STUFF; - only if link=shared
```

I was able to find a suggestion to use command line like variant=debug/somefeature=somevalue but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after some experimentation I was able to make it work through project-config.jam, here's a sample:

```
import option ;
import toolset ;

using msvc ;

toolset.flags msvc.compile CFLAGS <variant>release : "/GL /arch:SSE2 /fp:fast" : unchecked ;
toolset.flags msvc.compile CFLAGS <variant>debug : "/RTCc /RTC1 /GS" : unchecked ;
toolset.flags msvc.archive AROPTIONS <variant>release/<link>static : "/LTCG" : unchecked ;
toolset.flags msvc.link LINKFLAGS <variant>release/<link>shared : "/LTCG /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF" : unchecked ;
toolset.flags msvc.link LINKFLAGS <link>shared : "/PDB:c:\\Lib\\boost\\stage\\lib\\" : unchecked ;

option.set keep-going : false ;
```